# Question on fourier series expansion

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_function#Fourier_basis

It is known that [image]

form a basis for $L^2([0,1])$.

I want to see that $\{\sqrt2 \sin (2\pi nx+\pi x)\}, \{\sqrt 2 \cos (2\pi nx+\pi x)\}$, 1
also form a basis for $L^2([0,1])$. Assume that we already computed that these are orthonormal to each other.

(1) Is it true that those form a basis?

(2) How do I prove it? (heuristically or rigorously) Does it suffice to show that it is "complete"?

I'd appreciate any insight!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I take the integers and add one to every element we will again obtain a copy of the integers.  With this in mind, consider the input to $\{\sqrt{2}sin(2\pi nx+\pi x)\}$.

Comment: What do you mean by copy of the integers? And how does it show that it's a basis?

Comment: as sets of functions, they are the same just relabeled. What I mean by a copy of the integers is $\{n+1:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{n':n'\in\mathbb{Z}\}$